# http client on vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I am using vb 2008 .net 3.5.
I am trying to use sms api.
I have error on httpclient cannot find and I cannot find it on reference.

[image: screen shot]

sms provider code :

```cs
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("https://smsmisr.com/");
    client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
    var sendtime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(
    "api/webapi/?" +
    "username=XXXxx" +
    "&password=XXXXXX" +
    "&language= 3 Or 2 Or 1" +
    "&sender=Your Sender " +
    "&mobile=2012XXXXXX, 2011XXXX" +
    "&message=Encoded Message" +
    "&DelayUntil="+sendtime
    ).Result;
```

Comment: [Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.0.20710) + [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client - 4.0.30506](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/4.0.30506)

Comment: i install package on vs 2015 and not work give me error on PostAsJsonAsync any idea ?

Comment: Is this code meant to be used in an `Asp.Net`, `Asp.Net-Mvc`/`Razor` project? If not, you copied the wrong code. If it is, read this: [Call a Web API From a .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)